# Typescript: Defining interface of a nested object "that requires one of keys"

Tags: reactjs, typescript

**The goal is to restrict the developer from defining or accessing fields that the object doesn't have. Or to strictly define a deeply nested object or schema**

```
const theme: iTheme = {
  palletes: {
    primary: {
      main: "white",
      dark: "black"
    },
    secondary: {}
  }
};
```

*Problem is that I can't seem to tell typescript to require accessing one of primary|secondary. What I did is make both optional instead:*

```
/* Below is my attempt of interface iTheme and iContextWithTheme */

type ColorKeys = "main" | "dark" | "light";
type ColorKeysFields = { [K in ColorKeys]?: string };

type Palletes = "primary" | "secondary";
interface iTheme {
  palletes: { [K in Palletes]?: ColorKeysFields };
}

interface iContextWithTheme {
  theme: Theme;
}
```

It almost worked but I get `Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532)` then "react" is broken:

```
const color = (props: iContextWithTheme) => props.theme.palletes.primary.main;

/*
styled.div`
  color: ${props => props.theme.palletes.primary.main}
`;
*/
```

[image]

Comment: What do you expect your `color` function to do if a developer does not define a value for `palletes.primary`?

Comment: it's just a placeholder, what matters is react or typescript will allow me to access deeply until .main:
see `styled.div`
  `color: ${props => props.theme.pallete.primary.main}`. It could have been perfect because vscode intellisense is also working typing from the base of the object prop. until prop.theme.palletes.primary

Comment: You can't access past `primary` because the object might not have a `primary`.  Why don't you do a check?  `const color = (props: iContextWithTheme) => props.theme.palletes.primary ? props.theme.palletes.primary.main : "oopsie"`.  Not sure what your use case is here to point you at a real answer...

Comment: I edited the goal to make it clearer I'm trying to define a schema (validation) which hopefully typescript is capable of via interface or any other means. So apparently you are correct. But I want to express via typescript that one of primary | secondary is accessible but the closest I can achieve is to define both are optional instead. It's actually almost working, vscode intellisense is suggesting secondary or primary up to that point.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you want something like this

```js
type iTheme = {
  primary: ColorKeysField;
} | {
  secondary: ColorKeysField;
}
```